# How to copy an object if (and only if) it has a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, memoization

Context: I'm trying to memoize an object of a template class.  Right now, the class is a deeply nested data structure full of unique pointers, and so doesn't have a copy constructor (and so would be impossible to cache, as far as I know).  However, in the future, I would like to allow memoization if a copy constructor is available.  I tried the following code:

```
// some function here... {
  static std::unordered_map<State, Result> cache;

  return [c, ToValue](State state) {
      if (cache.find(state) != cache.end()) {
        std::cout << "retrieving Literal from cache\n";
        if (std::is_copy_constructible<Result>::value) {
          return cache[state];
        }
      }
      // calculate and return a Result
```

This code doesn't compile because Result doesn't have a copy constructor.  Is there any way to get around this?  Google is being quite unhelpful.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the code that doesn't compile

Comment: You can try `if constexpr( std::is_copy_constructible`...   , however you also should be returning something if that is false

Comment: If `Result` is not copy constructible, what do you want to return instead?

Comment: Think about [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) as return type. That way you can return something in case `Result` is not copy constructible.

Comment: None of this has anything to do with copy construction if I read the question right - please see my answer below.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, but I do return a different Result if the object isn't copy-constructible.  Didn't think to include it in the code snippet because it wasn't immediately relevant

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming the error you are getting is that `return cache[state];` cannot be compiled when the object is not copy-constructible. To fix that you can write:

```
if constexpr (std::is_copy_constructible<Result>::value) {
      return cache[state];
    }
```

If you are still having trouble then post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that has the error.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, the question is rather ill-defined and a bit confused, but do you need to actually *copy* an object in order to cache it?

Actually, no.  You can use `std::shared_ptr` to share *ownership* of the object between the creator, any consumers, and the cache.  If nothing else, this is much more efficient if your object is a complex one.  It will also work for any type of object, copyable or not.

Example (I'm going to use the word `Key` rather than `State`, for what I hope are obvious reasons).

Given these declarations:

```
class MyKey
{
    // ....
};

class MyCacheableObject
{
    // Constructor
    MyCacheableObject (int a, int b, int c) { ... }
    // ...
};

static std::unordered_map<MyKey, std::shared_ptr<MyCacheableObject>> cache;  // or std::map
```

You can do this (please note that there are other ways to make a `std::shared_ptr`, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)):

```
std::shared_ptr<MyCacheableObject> CreateCacheableObject (int a, int b, int c)
{
    return std::make_shared<MyCacheableObject> (MyCacheableObject (a, b, c));
}
```

And then, assuming you have a key you plan to use to retrieve the object from the cache later on, you can do:

```
MyKey someKey = ...;
std::shared_ptr<MyCacheableObject> newObject = CreateCacheableObject (1, 2, 3);

// ... setup / use `newObject` in whatever way is appropriate to your use-case 

cache [someKey] = newObject;
```

And you can of course retrieve the object from the cache (if it's in there) via:

```
auto retrievedObject = cache.find (someKey)
if (retrievedObject != cache.end())
    ...
```

So this question is not about whether an object is copyable at all.  It's about (shared) ownership and `std::shared_ptr` takes care of all that for you, you don't really have to think about it.  Oy vay.

There's a live demo, to show that this all compiles, [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z8rn9a1zjUx4QZLL).

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed response!  However, wouldn't using shared pointers allow the object within the cache to be modified?  The function could return a shared pointer to the object, and cache another shared pointer to it; then, the person using the function could mutate the object, causing the cache to now be bad.

Comment: Yes of course.  I don't know anything about your application so only you can decide if that is actually an issue for you.